# How to drag and drop lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want drag and drop functionality for my components.
Below is the screenshot for the components-

These are different components added in one component. I want that these components can drag and drop.
below is the code for this controller-

Component code:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="startId" type="string"/>
    <aura:attribute name="parentId" type="string"/>
    <div class="div1" id="div1" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}">
    <c:BP_CollapseComponent header="Reduce Operating Cost">
        <aura:set attribute="body">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Port_Availability" alt="Port Availability" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Port Availability">Port Availability</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Lubricant_Survey" alt="Lubricant Survey" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Lubricant Survey">Lubricant Survey</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Used_Oil_Analysis" alt="Used Oil Analysis" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Used Oil Analysis">Used Oil Analysis</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </aura:set>
    </c:BP_CollapseComponent>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div1" id="div1" ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}">
        <div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}">
    <c:BP_CollapseComponent header="Reduce Time Out Of Water">
        <aura:set attribute="body">
            <div class="slds-grid">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Scavange_Drain_Analysis" alt="Scavange Drain Analysis" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Scavange Drain Analysis">Scavange Drain Analysis</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Fuel_Saving" alt="Fuel Saving" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Fuel Saving">Fuel Saving</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-large-size--4-of-12" align="">
                                <figure class="slds-image slds-image--card">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-image__crop slds-image__crop--16-by-9">
                                        <img src="/resource/Castrol_Bio_Fuels" alt="Castrol Bio Fuels" />
                                    </a>
                                    <figcaption class="slds-image__title slds-image__title--card">
                                        <span class="slds-image__text slds-truncate" title="Castrol Bio Fuels">Castrol Bio Fuels</span>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </aura:set>
    </c:BP_CollapseComponent>
            </div>
    </div>

</aura:component>

controller code-
({
    myAction : function(component, event, helper) {

    },
    allowDrop: function(component, event, helper){
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    drop: function(component, event, helper){
        var drag = component.get("v.startId");
        var div = event.target.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(drag));
        document.getElementById(div).appendChild(fragment);
        var c = document.getElementById(div).children;
        var x = document.getElementById('drag1').parentElement.id;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        fragment.appendChild(document.getElementById(c[0].id));
        document.getElementById(component.get("v.parentId")).appendChild(fragment);
    },
     drag: function(component, event, helper){
          var parentId = document.getElementById(event.target.id).parentElement.id;
        component.set("v.startId",event.target.id);
        component.set("v.parentId",parentId);
    }
})
```

Comment: **What** are you trying to drag-drop? **Where** are you dragging-dropping? **Where** would you place this lightning component?

Kindly add details as much as possible, in concise and readable format. So, the community knows what is your requirement (clearly) and what you have done so far, then it is easy to answer. By looking at your question, details are vague and long code would make the reader **un-interested** as it is not easy to understand the requirement from the code itself. Thanks.

Comment: One approach is described in [Dragula drag and drop in a Lightning Component](https://force201.wordpress.com/2017/02/26/dragula-drag-and-drop-in-a-lightning-component/).

Comment: @Keith- The example given is for two components only as its taking ids of these two components. But i have more than two components. Then how can i do the same for each component?

Comment: This array argument can have as many elements in it as you like `dragula([from.getElement(), to.getElement()], ...`.